# chef-server-ctl reconfigure giving error ENETUNREACH

Tags: chef-infra

When I run `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` I get error:

> FATAL: Errno::ENETUNREACH: apt_repository[chef-stable] (private-chef::add_ons_repository line 15) had an error: Errno::ENETUNREACH: remote_file[/opt/opscode/embedded/cookbooks/cache/gpg.key] (/opt/opscode/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/apt/providers/repository.rb line 59) had an error: Errno::ENETUNREACH: Network is unreachable - connect(2) for "packagecloud.io" port 443

I have configured proxy related environment variables

```
http_proxy=http://172.16.x.y:3128
ftp_proxy=http://172.16.x.y:3128
HTTPS_PROXY=172.16.x.y:3128
https_proxy=http://172.16.x.y:3128
HTTP_PROXY=172.16.x.y:3128
```

If I run **wget** or **curl**, I get reply.

```
 wget https://www.google.com
--2016-12-09 07:20:09--  https://www.google.com/
Connecting to 172.16.x.y:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

Same test works with http also.
I am using Chef server 12.5.0 on Ubuntu 14

```
chef-server-ctl show-config
Starting Chef Client, version 12.5.0.current.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you actually can reach packagecloud.io -> https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/push-jobs/issues/100

Comment: Yes, I can connect. FYI. It is AWS VPC
wget https://packagecloud.io/
--2016-12-09 09:23:28--  https://packagecloud.io/
Connecting to 172.16.x.y:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.5’

Comment: There were some routing problems in AWS subnet configuration. After changing it, reconfigure worked. I am still confused why wget and curl worked.

Comment: I had a feeling it was a routing issue. Please rate if you think I helped you in any way :)